# How to query thread stack frame and local variables using GDB remote serial protocol?

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging

I'm trying to implement a GUI client for the [GDB remote serial protocol](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Protocol.html). So far I'm just reading the documentation, but I couldn't find how to get threads' stack frame and local variable informations. How can I get this informations?

Comment: "I'm trying to implement GDB remote serial protocol." -- are you trying to implement the GDB (local) part, the gdbserver (remote) part, or both?

Comment: @Employed Russian I am implementing UI. I think it's GDB (local) part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am implementing UI. I think it's GDB (local) part.

It sounds like your quesiton is:

Given that I have stopped a process (controlled by gdbserver) somewhere, how do I find out where (in which function) it is stopped (i.e. what is the current stack frame), what local variables are live at that point (where are they in memory)?

The bad news: to answer above questions, you'll have to re-implement 30-50% of GDB. You could start [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information) ("Finding variables" section in particular), but should probably read the entire [series](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/tag/debuggers).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was asking. Sadly, GDB seems too lower level for me. It seems I need to implement all the platform/language-specific resolution code. Based on your information, I decided to move to higher level LLDB API. Thanks for saving my time!